# Prove that a simple random walk is a martingale

Tags: time-series, random-walk, martingale

Note that $a$ has a mean of 0.

My approach:

$$X_t=X_{t-1}+a_t$$
$$E[X_{t+1}\mid X_1 + \dots+X_{t-1}]$$
$$=E[X_{t-1}+2a\mid X_1 + \dots+X_{t-1}]$$
$$=E[X_{t-1}\mid X_1 + \dots+X_{t-1}]+E[2a\mid X_1 + \dots+X_{t-1}]$$
$$=E[X_{t-1}\mid X_1 + \dots+X_{t-1}]+0$$
$$=E[X_{t-1}\mid X_1 + \dots+X_{t-1}]$$
$$=X_{t-1}$$
Am I doing something wrong here? shouldn't the end product be $X_t$?

Comment: You are calculating $E[X_{t+1}\mid X_1 + \dots+X_{t-1}]$ instead of $E[X_{t+1}\mid X_1 + \dots+X_{t-1}, X_t]$ or $E[X_{t}\mid X_1 + \dots+X_{t-1}]$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\begin{align}
E[X_{t+1} \mid X_1, \ldots, X_t]
&= E[X_t + a_{t+1} \mid X_1, \ldots, X_t]
\\
&= X_t + E[a_{t+1} \mid X_1, \ldots, X_t]
\\
&= X_t
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Let $\{X_t\}_{t\geq 1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $\Pr\{X_t=1\}=\Pr\{X_t=-1\}=1/2$. Define $\mathscr{F_t}=\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_t)$ and $M_t=X_1+\dots+X_t$. We have (equalities between conditional expectations holding almost surely)
$$
  \mathbb{E}[M_{t+1}\mid\mathscr{F_t}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}+M_t\mid\mathscr{F_t}] = \mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}\mid\mathscr{F_t}] + \mathbb{E}[M_t\mid\mathscr{F_t}].
$$
But $X_{t+1}$ is independent of $\mathscr{F_t}$, therefore, $\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}\mid\mathscr{F_t}]=\mathbb{E}[X_{t+1}]=0$. Also, $M_t$ is $\mathscr{F}_t$-measurable, hence, $\mathbb{E}[M_t\mid\mathscr{F_t}]=M_t$. It follows that $\mathbb{E}[M_{t+1}\mid\mathscr{F_t}]=M_t$ and $\{(M_t,\mathscr{F}_t)\}_{t\geq 1}$ is a martingale.